# Why is the builtin function `any(b'\x00')` behaving differently between python2 and python3?

Tags: python

The following example returns `True` in Python 2.x, while it returns `False` in Python 3.x

```
 python -c "print(any(b'\x00'))"
```

I can't find any explanation for the difference. `bool(b'\x00')` returns `True` in both Python 2.x and Python 3.x. I will expect the value true as the byte sequence contains an element there evaluates to True.

Which part of the language specification / documentation have I miss?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Python 2.x, when iterating over a byte string such as `b'\x00\x00\x00'`, its components are yielded by the iterator as sub strings:

```
>>> list(iter(b'\x00\x00\x00'))
['\x00', '\x00', '\x00']
>>> list(b'\x00\x00\x00')
['\x00', '\x00', '\x00']
```

This is because byte strings are just strings in Python 2 and thus show the same behaviour.

OTOH, if we use python 3, a byte string yields its contents as `int`s:

```
>>> list(iter(b'\x00\x00\x00'))
[0, 0, 0]
>>> list(b'\x00\x00\x00')
[0, 0, 0]
```

And from this difference, everything else is clear: as we already have noted, `bool(b'\x00')` is `True` while `bool(0)` is `False`.

The same holds true when iterating over one element strings: `list(b'\x00')` gives `['\x00']` in Py2 and `[0]` in Py3, `[bool(i) for i in b'\x00']` gives `[True]` in Py2 vs. `[False]` in Py3, and thus the difference.

Note that

```
any([bool(i) for i in b'\x00'])
any([i for i in b'\x00'])
any(b'\x00')
```

are semantically the same: iterate over the given object, get the truth value of every item and return of any of them is `True`.

TLDR: `b'\x00'[0] == b'\x00'` in Python 2 and `0` in Python 3.

Answer (score 2):

In Python2, b'\x00' is type `str`. In Python3, b'\x00' is \type `bytes`.

In Python3

> While bytes literals and representations are based on ASCII text, bytes objects actually behave like immutable sequences of integers, [...]

(https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#binaryseq)

Thus, in Python3, your byte string is composed of the integer 0, which is `False`. In Python2, it is composed of a `str` "character", which is nonempty, and therefore `True`.